# Выполняется только последняя функция на странице

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

вот такой код

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                        $('.arrow').click(function () {
                            if($(this).html() == '▼'){
                                $(this).html('▲');
                            }else{
                                $(this).html('▼');
                            }
                        });
                         $('.arrow').click(function () {

                            var thirdlvl = $(this).parent().find('.thirdlvl');
                            if(thirdlvl.css('display') == 'none'){
                                thirdlvl.css('display','block');
                            }else{
                                thirdlvl.css('display','none');
                            }

                        });        
                        $('.secondlvl li .thirdlvl li').parent().parent().find('.point').removeClass('point').addClass('arrow').html('▼');

                   });
```

Выводится вместе с вёрсткой которая подтягивается по ajax из php файла в котором собирается на `лёту`

Но на странице выполняется только

```
$('.secondlvl li .thirdlvl li').parent().parent().find('.point').removeClass('point').addClass('arrow').html('▼');
```

если я открываю консоль на этой странице и вставляю руками две предидущих функции click . Все сразу начинает работать. 
Почему?

Comment: ну первые две будут работать когда будет действие click. там же ястно написано $('.arrow').click .... а последнее просто находится в $(document).ready т.е будет срабатывать когда страница загрузится

Comment: @Arsen так кликаю ничего не происходит, если в консоль вставить все клики срабатывают

Comment: ну по шагам проверьте где проблема, например в начале поставте console.log . посмотрите може даже не заходит в этот обработчик 
 $('.arrow').click(function () { console.log('проверка')  }

Comment: @Arsen в click действительно не заходит после клика, почему это происходит?

Comment: ну это означает что на сайте у вас что то налазит на данную кнопку... и всё ))) перекрывает её,  через браузер инспектором проверьте

Comment: @Arsen нет ничего там не налазиет, кнопка лежит с верху и кликабельна, могут быть еще причины?

Comment: Проблем может быть много, если уверенны что JS файл подключается, надо проверить html селектор, браузер и т.д

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Выводится вместе с вёрсткой которая подтягивается по ajax из php файла в котором собирается на лёту

Все здесь ясно, вы вешаете обработчик на элемент которого еще нет на странице,

вместо этого

`$('.arrow').click(function () { .... });`

пропишите

`$(document).on('click', '.arrow', function () { .... });`

Документация по методу `$.on()` находится [здесь](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On)

Comment: Вот оно ! Большое спасибо почитаю.

Comment: Если это решило вашу проблему то поставьте галочку

Comment: простите не благодарный какой =)